# Angular 2 testing with karma and jasmine

Tags: unit-testing, angular, karma-jasmine

I have written only one test case and when i run "npm test" from command line in windows i am getting the following error. Don't know what is the issue

```
> ng test --single-run

PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0) ERROR
  {
    "stack": "(SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading typescript\n\tError loading typescript as \"typescript\" from node_modules/@angular/tsc-wrapped/test/collector.spec.js",
    "originalErr": {},
    "line": 792,
    "sourceURL": "node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"
  }
```

PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.476 secs / 0 secs)

npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.

spec.ts

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By }              from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Router} from '@angular/router';
import { DebugElement, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA }    from '@angular/core';

import { myComponent } from './myComponent.component';

describe('myComponent ', () => {

  let comp:    myComponent ;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<myComponent >;
  let de:      DebugElement;
  let el:      HTMLElement;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ], //to avoid routing
        declarations: [ myComponent ], // declare the test component
    });

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(myComponent );

    comp = fixture.componentInstance; // myComponent test instance

    // query for the title <h1> by CSS element selector
    de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.left-side-card'));
    el = de.nativeElement;
  });
   it('should display title', () => {
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(el.textContent).toContain('My Title');
    });
});
```

what should i do?

I am new to angular 2. The environment was already setup in my project. I was practicing to write test cases for the components.

Comment: update your post with the test case code along with the steps which you followed to setup karma

Comment: @Aravind updated with test case code

Comment: is it a form element? **.left-side-card** corresponds to a form element?

Comment: @Aravind - no it is just a div with ".left-side-card" class name